# how to focus on the tab when alert was active?

Tags: javascript

for example 
I use chrome, I create a new tabs we call it "tabA" in tabA we run the javascript 
`setTimeout("alert('test')",10000)`

in addition create a new tab quickly and browsing some web page, after 10 sec tabA javascript active pop-out the alert message, but i need to click on tabA then I can see the alert message.

Is it possible to auto switch to tabA when it was active? or it was case by security problem, chrome/ Firefox was block this function?

I have try hard to explain my problem
hope you guys will understand

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to a tab you opened from your website, in that way:

```
const newTabs = [];
newTabs.push(window.open(<OTHER_TAB_URL>));
newTabs[0].focus();
```

You can put a timeout on the focus or put a condition.

As for changing the active tab from the new tab when the alert pops, sadly, you can't. You can only switch focus to tabs you opened yourself.

Comment: Actually I want to create an item price monitoring script on Tampermonkey.
Each tabs for an item, for example when the price was lower than $10, it will activate an alert to remind me.
But it can't auto switch to alert active tabs, it always make me missed the best price

anyway thanks for help :D

Comment: If you want to keep exploring these options, you can have a look at writing a chrome extension that utilizes the [Chrome Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)